# How to use get_properties to get RSSI in RF24?

Tags: wireless, rf

As picture below, how to use get_properties ? I fail to understand [AN625](http://community.silabs.com/mgrfq63796/attachments/mgrfq63796/BluetoothandWiFi/8086/1/Si446X%20API%20DESCRIPTIONS.pdf), how to use get_properties to get RSSI ?

> [image]
>
> Adding source code based on RH_RF24 functions.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <RH_RF24.h>

// Singleton instance of the radio driver
RH_RF24 rf24;


uint8_t Recieve_Data[20];

uint8_t receive_buffer[RH_RF24_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
uint8_t receive_buffer_length = sizeof(receive_buffer);

uint8_t Rssi;

unsigned long Micro_Time;

uint8_t status[8];
uint8_t buf[RH_RF24_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
uint8_t len = sizeof(buf);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  if (!rf24.init())
    Serial.println("init failed");
  // Defaults after init are 434.0MHz, modulation GFSK_Rb5Fd10, power 0x10
   while(!rf24.setFrequency(443));
  rf24.setModemConfig(rf24.GFSK_Rb50Fd100);  //设置成GFSK_Rb50Fd100
}


void loop()
{
  rf24.setModeRx();
  delay(100);
  rf24.setModeIdle();
  rf24.command(RH_RF24_CMD_GET_INT_STATUS, NULL, 0, status, sizeof(status));
  Serial.print("Id   ");
  for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
  {
    Serial.print((uint8_t)status[i]);
    Serial.print("   ");
  }
  Serial.println();
  /*
    if (status[2])
    {
      uint8_t modem_status[6];
      rf24.command(RH_RF24_CMD_GET_MODEM_STATUS, NULL, 0, modem_status, sizeof(modem_status));
      delay(100);
      for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
      {
        Serial.print(modem_status[i]);
        Serial.print("   ");
      }
      Serial.println();
    }
  */
  delay(400);
}
```

Comment: What part are you using, as that function is only available for Silicon Labs Si4460/4461/4463/4464 family of transceivers chip, and the equivalent HopeRF RF24/26/27 family of chips and the HopeRF RFM24W/26W/27W modules

Comment: @Gerben  I use Si4463.

Comment: As coded in the ["Github - lora_chisterapi/lib/radiohead/RH_RF24.cpp"](https://github.com/Snootlab/lora_chisterapi/blob/master/lib/radiohead/RH_RF24.cpp), `firstProperty = (GROUP << 8) + (START_PROP)` and `uint8_t* values` + `uint8_t count` are used to stored the read properties.

Comment: @J.Piquard  Could you write an example, I don't understand it well. Seemly, I can get RSSI just use RH_RF24::command as in web you given.

Comment: Instead of using the `command()` as a static call (`RH_RF24::command`), the best approach should be to use a class instantiation and declare a `RH_RF24 rf24;` before `setup()` function and initialize the instance with a `rf24.init()` call. So, could you provide what source code you have tried in your Arduino in order to give you a more concrete example ?

Comment: @J.Piquard  I am very sorry, I don't know how to edit code, so , although I have add them in my question , but they are not clear.

Comment: @lanse7pty, I have formatted your added source code, but wait for the peer review. Your source code seems good, but be careful with the use of `sizeof(status)` in the request `rf24.command()` (only available when the size of the item is 1 = `sizeof(uint8_t)`) then `i <= 8` in the for-loop display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the `RH_RF24 rf24;`(Singleton instance of the radio driver), read a series of properties is really simple.

- The properties shall be in the same GROUP,
- Up to 16 properties could be read in the same request,

> Hereafter is a example to read from `SYNC_CONFIG` to `SYNC_BITS_7_0` (5
>   properties).

**Step 1** - Declare your own `uint8_t sync_stat[5];` or use the still declared `uint8_t status[8];`.

```
 uint8_t sync_stat[5];
```

**Step 2** - The `firstProperty` is in fact the first property to be read and `count` is the number successive properties to be read (from `SYNC_CONFIG = 0x1100` to `SYNC_BITS_7_0 = 0x1104`.

```
// And check the returned code
if (rf24.get_properties(SYNC_CONFIG,sync_stat,5)) {
    // sync_stat[0]= SYNC_CONFIG
    // ...
    // sync_stat[4]= SYNC_BITS_7_0
}
```

> Then, the equivalent `command()` is:

```
uint8_t buf[3];
buf[0] = SYNC_CONFIG >> 8;
buf[1] = 5;
buf[2] = SYNC_CONFIG & 0xff;
if (rf24.command(RH_RF24_CMD_GET_PROPERTY, buf, sizeof(buf),sync_stat,5)) {
    // Same array
}
```